# Upload ViewOnly file to OneDrive

Tags: c#, .net, onedrive

I'm playing the [Microsoft.Live](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641952.aspx) namespace in Visual studio. The uploading of files to Onedrive poses no problems to us. But we can't seem to make the uploaded files `ViewOnly`. On the MSDN page (see above), I can't seem to find any info about this. How (What method) must I use to upload files as readonly?

Current code for uploading data:

```
LiveOperationResult operationResult;
var liveClient = await getLiveConnectClient();

// upload
operationResult = await liveClient.UploadAsync(folderPath, fileName, stream, OverwriteOption.Overwrite);
dynamic resultUpload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(operationResult.RawResult);
```

This code still edits on the uploaded file. What I accutually want is to create a link with option "view only".

Any ideas, suggestions?

Comment: I don't think you set share permissions on upload. I believe you can only set them at "share" time.

Comment: Uploading the files as mentionned above has already put them as shared. The `Operationresult`contains a link to the shared file.

Comment: So you're implicitly sharing your entire one drive with the world?

Comment: No, off course not. The Onedrive itself (where this application refers to) is an instance only accessible within the current company structure. Outsiders have no access to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer after some (desperate) searching

On the following msdn-page [File and folder properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659731.aspx) there a reference on how to link to files.
When you wish to achieve a `view-only reference` you have to perform a Webrequest of the following URI

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/FILEID/shared_read_link?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

FileID & AccessToken can be easily found using the SDK.
```

The result of the webrequest is JSON-data which looks as follows:

```
{
   "link": "https://onedrive.live.com/redir.aspx?....."
}
```

Input the link in the browsers show the file, but the ability to change it has been disabled. I hope this may be of some use to someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are referring to the read-only bit on file systems and the LiveSDKs does not support a read-only option on files.

Comment: Well perhaps my ReadOnly tag is somewhat misleading. The LiveSDK support a view-Only option. Thats the one i'm searching for.

Comment: View-only has to do with sharing with other users. You can't prevent the uploading user from editing the file.

Answer (score 0):

When a file is uploaded with one drive, the uploader always has access to the file. You can't set it to read-only, or view-only for that said user.

A possible work around would be to have a separate account for file uploads that uploads to a shared folder with view-only permissions already set. Users would then "view" the uploaded file as the non uploaded user from another account, preventing file access modification.

Comment: And that is exactly the implementation that i did....... The problem was (even when not logged in as the uploading-user) that the returned link (inside the properties) was the link to edit not to view. Thus I was searching for a way to find the `shared_read_link` instead of the `shared_edit_link`. Which I did with the method mentionned above. Because even when not logged in the `shared_edit_link` still provides you with the possibillity to edit the file.